# Incrementing login_count with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I'd like to have the login_count attribute increment each time the user enters my site via explicit login or remember me login.  Currently Authlogic only increments login_count per explicit login.  Has anyone else done this, or does anyone know where to customize this inside of the plugin?

Comment: Can you describe why you need this feature?

Comment: Back-end analytics. Keeping track of visits to the site - regardless of why I need this feature, I'm concerned with how I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your user session class as follows:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  def persist_by_cookie
    r = super
    User.increment_counter(:login_count, unauthorized_record.id) if r
    r
  end
end
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this code. As per Authlogic code this should work. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: This did not, but I don't think as a result of your code.  For some reason my Authlogic system is incrementing the login_count rapidly throughout a session.  Not sure why, but I found a way around this entire issue.  Much thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController`  to increment the counter.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    

  before_filter :increment_visit_count    

private

  def increment_visit_count
    User.increment_counter(:visit_count, current_user.id) if current_user
  end    
end
```

**Note**: This solution requires a new column `visit_count` in your `users` table.

Comment: Won't this also increment the counter while the user is on the site moving from page to page?

Comment: Yes, it will. I read your requirements wrong. I will update the answer with the correct reply.

Comment: Thank you in advance of the reply :)